# Xamarin.Android Exception with FCM & Parse

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm able to implement Firebase Notifications and send notifications to the client from the Firebase console successfully.  The problem arises when I'm using the Parse SDK to send the notification via the Parse Dashboard.  I'm using Xamarin.Android, and the documentation isn't quite there with Native Android with FCM & Parse.  I noticed when sending the notification via the Parse Dashboard, I get the following exception on the client:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
```

When the parse documentation tells me to implement the following manifest below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.xamarin.fcmexample" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="20" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="g" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Wondering if I'm missing anything to get Xamarin.Android + Parse SDK + FCM working.  Thanks.

Comment: anyone got any leads on this? Having same problem.